# Replacing USB251xB/xBI USB 2.0 HUB Controller

Tags: pcb-design, usb, microchip, hardware, usb-hub

Due to Chip Shortage problem, I need to replace Microchip [USB251xB/xBi USB 2.0 Hi-Speed Hub Controller](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/00001692c.pdf) with [USB3503T-I/ML](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/00001584C.pdf)

I'm using only two USB 2.0 ports.
the chip will be used in an Industrial Desktop PC.

I was wondering if there is a reason why this replacement might not be a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best people to ask are the Microchip application engineers.  That's kinda their entire purpose of existing.  There will be a 'contact' button on their website.

Answer (score 0):

The replacement (USB3503T-I/ML) uses HSIC for the upstream and the original uses a regular USB port (USB251xB). Those ICs are not compatible with eachother, they may work in your solution but you probably need some changes to your board.

Since this question is a few months old I assume by now you already realised the difference, but perhaps it may help someone else.